Handling Dependency Errors During Docker Installation on Ubuntu 18.04
I am a beginner with Linux and I am trying to install Docker on an instance that has Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-106-generic x86_64). I am following the guide I found here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
The first step involves running this series of commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl

However, when I try to run sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl, I get an error saying:
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gpgv but it is not going to be installed or
                gpgv2 but it is not going to be installed or
                gpgv1 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: ubuntu-keyring but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.6.12ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.6) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 ca-certificates : Depends: openssl (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                            debconf-2.0
 curl : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.24) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


When I try to do what the error suggests, that is, run the command apt --fix-broken install, it doesn't work and throws the following error:
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 56%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 609 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb ...
open2: Illegal seek at /usr/share/perl/5.26/IPC/Open3.pm line 210.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 29
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


What can I do?
I am trying to install Docker on an instance that has Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-106-generic x86_64).
